# Task watchdog gets triggered during Bluetooth initialization

Tags: arduino-ide, bluetooth, esp32, watchdog

The board ESP32-Dev-WROOM-32D cannot establish a bluetooth connection due to the task watchdog. Here's my code:

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
//check if Bluetooth is enabled
#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test"); 
  Serial.println("The device started!");
}
```

The program runs fine until `SerialBT.begin("ESP32test");` where it freezes, and does not continue to run. The message `The device started!` is not printed. Instead, the task watchdog gets triggered after some time: `E (24791) task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered.`

Is there any way to turn off the task watchdog? Or is there any other issue?

Comment: Try adding `esp_task_wdt_reset();` before `SerialBT.begin(...)`.

Comment: Nothing changes, watchdog still gets triggered

Answer (score 1):

`SerialBT.begin("ESP32test")` is hanging, and because ESP32 doesn't deal well with code that hangs, so it complains about it.

ESP32 runs a Real-Time OS ([FreeRTOS](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/freertos.html)).
The fact that it is a real-time OS means that execution of code needs to be guaranteed to finish within a certain time-frame. You'll often see RTOS functions containing the time limit in which that a blocking function should finish executing, such as:

```c
    uart_wait_tx_done(uart_num, 100); // wait timeout is 100 RTOS ticks (TickType_t)
```

(from [ESP-IDF docs](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/uart.html))

FreeRTOS comes with a task API. Each task can execute code, but they need to give other tasks the chance to execute code too. I think that when a task blocks, it doesn't allow other tasks to do work on the same CPU. (but I can't find sources to back this up)

`setup()` runs in one of the RTOS tasks, and when `SerialBT.begin()` blocks the task for too long, the task watch dog complains that the task is hanging.
If the task is blocked by some kind of looping code, then it generally helps to run `vTaskDelay()` to yield the task to the task watchdog for a bit.

Because your task is blocked by a single call, there isn't much to do about it, given that `SerialBT.begin()` doesn't seem allow you to specify when it should time out.